# Excel table data transpose

Tags: excel

I have an excel table in the following format that contains data for a process

***Sample Data:***

[image]

I want the data to be transformed from the input model to the output model. My actual data contains 22 process and 6 sub-processes with 16,000 Unique IDs. Thus manual transformation is not possible. Please suggest an algorithm that I can replicate on a large scale.

Answer (score 0):

I think `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` can help you. Try below formula as per my screenshot. Put the formula to `D9` cell and drag then down and right as needed.

```
=INDEX($C$3:$H$5,MATCH($B9,$A$3:$A$5,0),MATCH($A9&D$8,$C$2:$H$2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Then please mark as answered. Tick mark the answer.